# NextJS - build multiple projects at once with static export?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I have a small Next.js project, all the data comes from multiple API endpoints that look like this:

```
https://enpoint.com/some-query/project1
```

The API is projected in a way that it could reply with different data for different sites:

```
https://enpoint.com/some-query/project1
https://enpoint.com/some-query/project2
https://enpoint.com/some-query/project3
```

Right now I'm doing `next build && next export` as all I need is a static export. Once I run this command I'm getting `/out/project1` with all the files necessary to run the site.

My question is - what's the preferred way of altering Next.js build process so during `next build && next export` it will run API calls to `https://enpoint.com/some-query/project1`, build `out/project1` and then repeat the same steps for `project2` and `project3`?

Once I build my project I want to end up with:

```
/out/project1
/out/project2
/out/project3
```

Any ideas? I've been looking in the docs but with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward solution I know is to run the build process multiple times with different environmental variables.

**Setup build commands**

```
"build": "npm-run-all --parallel build:project1 build:project2 build:project3",
"build:project1": "PROJECT_ENV=project1 next build",
"build:project2": "PROJECT_ENV=project2 next build",
"build:project2": "PROJECT_ENV=project3 next build",
```

**Call different API endpoints based on the env variables**

```js
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  switch(process.env.PROJECT_ENV) {
    case 'project1': 
      // fetch project 1 data
    case 'project2': 
      // fetch project 2 data
    case 'project3': 
      // fetch project 3 data
  }
  return {
    props: {...}
  }
}
```

This might not be the best answer but I hope it helps.